# How can I rewrite this javascript code to C++11?

Tags: javascript, c++, lambda, c++11, closures

This is the javascript closure code I saw at Javascript Definitive Guide. I'd like to write it as C++11

```
var uniqueID1 = (function()
{
    var id = 0;
    return function() { return id++; };
})();
```

This is the cpp code I wrote. But it isn't be compiled. Can C++11 represent the same expression?

```
auto c = []() -> int (*)() { int x = 0; return [&x]() -> int { return x++; }};
```

I'm using VS2010

**Edit:**
This is the full javascript sample code I made. You can test easily how the code works at your web browser.

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">
var uniqueID1 = (function()
{
    var id = 0;
    return function() { return id++; };
})();

var uniqueID2 = (function()
{
      var id = 0;
      return function() { return id++; };
})();
</script>
</head>

<body>
        <input value = "uniqueid1" type="button" OnClick="alert(uniqueID1());"></input>
        <input value = "uniqueid2" type="button" OnClick="alert(uniqueID2());"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, that's the least C++-like C++ I've ever seen. I wasn't even aware you could return a newly-created function by value in any C-derivative language. **EDIT**: you can't, as Nicol Bolas mentioned.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, first let's break down what your JavaScript does.

```
function()
{
    var id = 0;
    return function() { return id++; };
}
```

This creates a function. A function with no name, which takes no parameters. This function, when called, will return a new function. The inner function will have access to a locally scoped variable, and this variable will be part of the state of that inner function.

Each time this function is called, it will return a *new* function. That new function will have its own state (`var id = 0;` has to do something, after all). Each call of the outer function will return a new function with new state.

This:

```
(function()
{
    var id = 0;
    return function() { return id++; };
})
```

Wraps the function in a pair of parenthesis. This is needed for operator precedence rules, to allow this to work:

```
(function()
{
    var id = 0;
    return function() { return id++; };
})()
```

This creates a function, and then *calls* the function. That's what the last `()` do at the end. It calls the outer function, which creates an inner function with its own scope and returns it.

In this expression, the outer function *is lost*. It's gone; you can't access it anymore. You created it for just long enough to call it, then let it drop into the trashcan of garbage collection.

Given all of this, we can see that this statement:

```
var uniqueID1 = (function()
{
    var id = 0;
    return function() { return id++; };
})();
```

Creates the outer function, calls the function which returns a new function, and then stores the *inner* function in a variable called `uniqueID1`.

If you need proof that this is true, try this in your HTML:

```
var uniqueMaker = function()
{
    var id = 0;
    return function() { return id++; };
};

var uniqueID1 = uniqueMaker();
var uniqueID2 = uniqueMaker();
```

You'll get the same answer as your copy-and-paste version.

If we want C++ code to mimic this, we need to perform each step with proper C++ code.

First, the inner function. In C++, lexical scoping does not exist. So you cannot return functions that reference variables in other scopes. You can only return a lambda that has a *copy* of variables from another scope. Also, lambdas cannot modify scope unless you explicitly allow it. Thus, the inner code must look like this:

```
int id = 0;
return [=]() mutable { return ++id; };
```

That's all well and good, but now we need to create a lambda that will return this stateful lambda function. In C++, functions that have state are not the same as function pointers. And since the type of a lambda is compiler-defined, there's no way to type its name. Therefore, we must employ `std::function` as the return type of the outer function.

```
[]() -> std::function<int()>
{
  int x = 0;
  return [=]() mutable { return x++; };
}
```

This creates a lambda function that, when called, will return an inner function with its own state. State that is independent from any subsequent calls to this function. Just like the JavaScript example.

Now, that's not enough. Remember, your JavaScript creates the outer function, calls it, and stores *only* its return value. The outer function *itself* is discarded. So we need to mimic this. Fortunately, this is easy enough in C++; it looks just like JavaScript:

```
([]() -> std::function<int()>
{
  int x = 0;
  return [=]() mutable { return x++; };
})()
```

Lastly, we stick it in a variable:

```
auto uniqueID1 = ([]() -> std::function<int()>
{
  int x = 0;
  return [=]() mutable { return x++; };
})();
```

The type of `uniqueID1` will be `std::function<int()>`. It won't be the type of the outer function. The outer function is just a temporary that was used to create the inner scope.

Comment: Still not compiled. `error C3491: 'x': a by-value capture cannot be modified in a non-mutable lambda` Should I test it by gcc?

Comment: @Benjamin: Then make it mutable, as shown in the edited version ;)

Comment: I didn't know about the keyword, thanks. It has been compiled but the  state is not keeping. `printf("%d\n", c()); printf("%d\n", c()); printf("%d\n", c());` When I call this code, I expected it prints `0 1 2`, but it prints gabarge value. `3215840 3215840 3215840`

Comment: @Benjamin well, `c()` returns a function, so it's not garbage but the function. Shouldn't you write `c()()` instead.

Comment: @PeterT I already tried. It prints `0 0 0` I have no idea what's the problem.

Comment: @Benjamin well `0 0 0` is the correct response, if you want it to print `0 1 2` then you should declare `x` as static `static int x =0;` or save the result of c(), because `c()` actually sets `x=0` every time you call it.

Comment: @Benjamin: Of course it returns `0 0 0`. `c()` returns a *function*, which stores state. Each call to `c()` returns a different function with it's own, *separate* state. Unless I'm reading your JavaScript code wrong, that's what your JavaScript code does too. Note that your JavaScript ends with `()`, which *calls* the outer function. Thus `uniqueID1` stores the function returned by the outer function. See my edit for details.

Comment: @NicolBolas Gotcha! It was my fault. `auto b = c(); printf("%d\n", b()); printf("%d\n", b()); printf("%d\n", b());` I saved c()'s result to b as you said. And it works as I expected. Thank you.

Comment: @Benjamin: I've completely rewritten my answer to explain how the JavaScript code works and how to replicate its effects in C++.

Comment: I think this is a good translation of literally what the javascript does, and it makes good use of c++11 features. Unfortunately it is ugly, non-idiomatic and overly complicated for its intended purpose. For example: The outer function that is called immediately is a javascript idiom to create a new lexical scope. I think repeating that idiom in C++ is out of place.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not asking for a literal translation, but rather how to best express this construct in C++. Your JavaScript construct is in some sense "faking a constructor", and your ID generator is best expressed as a simple *class* in C++. Then you just make instances of that class:

```
class UniqueID
{
    unsigned int value;
public:
    UniqueID() : value(0) { }
    unsigned int operator()() { return ++value; }
};
```

Usage:

```
UniqueID gen1, gen2;

some_function(gen1());
another_function(gen2());
Foo x(Blue, "Jim", gen1());
```

This approach is lighter-weight than a `std::function` wrapper, although a straight-up lambda will produce a similar data structure (though you cannot know its type name). You can initialize `value` to `-1` if you want the first ID to be 0 (though it might be useful to reserve 0 as a special value).

Comment: That's not the same thing. If I understand JavaScript correctly, each call to the JavaScript should return a new instance of the function with *new* state.

Comment: @NicolBolas: OK, edited. The multiple lambda plus `std::function` approach is interesting in a fun sort of way, but it comes at a considerably higher cost than the idiomatic translation.

Comment: I don't know if I would call it "idiomatic". C++11 will have its own idioms, and Lambdas are going to be a part of it. Having to create a class for this kind of thing is a relic of the past. Idioms change.