# Lambda functions to implement functional port of D3.JS to C++11

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, functional-programming, d3.js

Would the lambda functions of C++11 be able to handle the functional aspects of D3.JS if one were to attempt a partial port to C++?

What sort of functional programming and loose typing features will I most likely find difficult to transfer from JS to C++11?

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, you should look at [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/).

Comment: See [How can I rewrite this javascript code to C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075239/how-can-i-rewrite-this-javascript-code-to-c11).